# How to Add / Create New Store in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've read many tutorials out there but I couldn't find any right (tested) information on how to create new store in Magento 1.7

I would like to add my new store in new /folder/
e.g. www.mymage.com/newstore/

Do I need to copy index.php and .htaccess?

Can you please give me correct modification between files?

Add category
system>manage stores
etc

Ref:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-creating-multiple-online-storefronts-part1/

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Here it it

http://magento-rohan.blogspot.in/2012/10/magento-managing-multiple-website-stores.html

you will do this easily using above link 
also for video

www.magentocommerce.com/magento-on-the-fly/multiple-sites/

Comment: I like it when there are no videos involved... +1

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy (and modify) index.php and .htaccess. You also need to create a bunch of symlinks.
This [tutorial](http://docs.nexcess.net/multiplestorefronts) covers it all.

Answer (score 0):

i'm currently working with Magento (newbie).
To create e new store or website in Magento
1. Create folder "mystore/website" under emagento directory

```
2. Copy & paste files: index.php and .htaccess form main directory and change the following in index.php (.htaccess remains unchanged)
    Line 51: 
        $mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/../app/Mage.php';
    Line 81: 
        /* Store or website code */
        $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'mystore/website';
    Line 84:
        /* Run store or run website */
        $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website/store';
```

Then we have to work in Backend.
- Create website
-crete a certain store for this website
-create roo category and add products
-create store view (yourstore code)
-create CMS pages
This is just the way we need to follow when creating new website, based on your requirements there are certain other files that need modification.
Hope i helped somehow :)